# Slumdog millionaire (4)

Tags: knowledge

My Indian friend Jamal recently participated in the well-known TV quiz
show ***[Who wants to be a millionaire?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_Wants_to_Be_a_Millionaire)***. You might have heard or read about Jamal's spectacular success; the media reported on it extensively.

Here is what Jamal told us about his 500 Euro question:

> I knew the answer to the 500 Euro question right away, even before Prem
>   Kumar started to read the four answers; however, I didn't spot it until
>   he was done reading.
>
> Answer A was the exact opposite of what the man normally asked for.
>   B was much too Grecian for him, and when you made it with one of those,
>   you usually didn't use vodka (which he preferred).  Answer C described
>   the type of glass it was contained in, and not how it was made, and I
>   certainly didn't recall him constantly being at a New Year's celebration.
>   Hence I gave D as my answer.  Prem asked if it was my final decision.
>   I said yes. Correct, once again, a big shiny smile from Prem, and we
>   moved on to the next question.

What was the 500 Euro question?
What were the four possible answers A, B, C, D?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The 500 Euro question was:

> How does James Bond usually order his favorite drink?

With answers:

> A. stirred, not shaken
>  B. with an olive
>  C. in a champagne glass
>  D. shaken, not stirred

Comment: I prefer the olive over the Ouzo that others have answered.  Olives usually go with a Gin martini.  
The question could also be: How does James Bond order a Martini.

Answer (score 4):

The 500 Euro question was:

> What was the favourite drink of James Bond?

With answers:

> A: Martini stirred, not shaken.
>  B: Ouzo.
>  C: Champagne. Cocktail glass.
>  D: Martini shaken, not stirred.

I didn't try too hard to fill in the answers.

Answer (score 2):

Question:

> What drink does James Bond like to order?

Answer:

> A - Stirred martini
>  B - Ouzo
>  C - Champagne glass
>  D - Shaken martini